# Change svg image with css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I'm trying to change an SVG icon created by CreatableSelect in React, but I'm trying to use only CSS to do this.

I want to change the "d" element inside the svg tag for this:

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-chevron-down" viewBox="0 0 16 16"> <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/> </svg>`

This is the element created by the library:

```css
.css-1hb7zxy-IndicatorsContainer .css-tlfecz-indicatorContainer svg>path {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='currentColor' class='bi bi-chevron-down' viewBox='0 0 16 16'><path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/></svg>") no-repeat 0 0 !important;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class=" css-tlfecz-indicatorContainer" aria-hidden="true">
  <svg height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="css-tj5bde-Svg">
    <path d="M4.516 7.548c0.436-0.446 1.043-0.481 1.576 0l3.908 3.747 3.908-3.747c0.533-0.481 1.141-0.446 1.574 0 0.436 0.445 0.408 1.197 0 1.615-0.406 0.418-4.695 4.502-4.695 4.502-0.217 0.223-0.502 0.335-0.787 0.335s-0.57-0.112-0.789-0.335c0 0-4.287-4.084-4.695-4.502s-0.436-1.17 0-1.615z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Also, tried with a URL from font awesome free to test, but failed to.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: I tried to clarify your question and put together a demo so we can see the problem. Please revise further as needed.

Comment: You can't change any properties in a background image. If your icon is inlined you can actually change the `d` attribute like so `path{ d: path()}`